# Use .bind(this) in style attribute

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple function:

```js
fullscreen2 () {
    console.log('test')
}
```

And I'm trying to pass the current element to it:

```js
<div style={this.fullscreen2.bind(this)}>
```

The function does not seem to trigger. This works however:

```js
<div style={this.fullscreen2()}>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it depends on whether you use `React.createClass` (which have auto-bind) or ES6 classes.

> `<div style={this.fullscreen2()}>`

Call the function `this.fullscreen2` and pass its return value to the `style` of this `div` tag.

> `<div style={this.fullscreen2.bind(this)}>`

Bind the function's `this` object (`this.fullscreen2`) to the current `this` (e.g. the instance class object). [What is the return type of `Function.bind`?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Well, this method returns a new function, so you pass to the `style` object a new function!

The fix would be:

> `<div style={this.fullscreen2.bind(this)()}>`

But once again, you might not need to bind, refer to Shubham Khatri's answer for an example without bind.

Bind is useful only if you need to access: `this.state`, `this.props` or similar instance-specific attributes that might be lost due to the way you define your function.

To understand more how does this works (when my function lose the context, when it does not), look around how [lexical scope](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/20/javascript-scope-closures) works in JavaScript.

Comment: I want to access the current element, or rather it's properties, I do this nwo  with the ref-attribute, but that seems overly complex.

Comment: Why do you need to access to the current properties of the object? Do you mean DOM properties?

Comment: I need the objects size so I can use css translations to transition it to fullscreen, specifically I'm using getBoundingClientRect

Comment: So you need to use `ref` to store a reference to the DOM node on the instance class, this is another problem.

Comment: I'm using ref now, but it seems kind of weird to do it this way, basically giving the funciton an attribute, just so that I can pass it in the next attribute seems redundant, ref would make more sense to me if it was about referencing other attributes, like `<label for=... >` but this might be the react way?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to bind the valye to the function, you ca directly pass it in the arguments like

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  function2 = (val, val2) => {
    console.log('in here', val, val2);
    if(val == '2')  {
      return {
          backgroundColor: 'blue'
      }
    } else {
      return {
          backgroundColor: 'orange'            
      }
    }
      
  } 
  render() {
    return (
     <div style={this.function2('2', '3')}>Hello World</div>
    )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: The actual function I want to use needs to know what element is calling it, that's why I want to bind.

Comment: You can pass an I'd in the parameters that will identify who has called it

Comment: I would like to avoid this if possible, i'm currently using ref

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.fullscreen2 = this.fullscreen2.bind(this);
  }

  fullscreen2 () {
    console.log('test')
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.fullscreen2}>fullscreen</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default App;
```